# How to make this type script compatible from react tutorial?

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

This has quite a few errors when using in type script

```
import { useLocation, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

function QueryNavLink({ to, ...props }) {
  let location = useLocation();
  return <NavLink to={to + location.search} {...props} />;
}

TS7031: Binding element 'to' implicitly has an 'any' type.
TS2741: Property 'children' is missing in type '{ to: string; }' but required in type 'NavLinkProps'.
```

I am not quite sure how to resolve this?
thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This part of the React Router tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#custom-behavior) demonstrates how to compose a `<NavLink>` to add a custom behaviour, that simply "persists" the URL search params.

In that case, the props are the same as the NavLink, so you could type them the same as well:

```
function QueryNavLink({ to, ...props }: NavLinkProps) {
  let location = useLocation();
  return <NavLink to={to + location.search} {...props} />;
}
```